# Calculating standard errors for mean regression weights in R (LSEM, lavaan, RI-CLPM)

Tags: r, regression

I am looking at the relationship of 2 variables using an RI-CLPM (Random Intercept Cross-Lagged Panel Model). I am furthermore looking at possible age effects using LSEM (Local Structural Equation Modeling). After fitting the LSEM I extracted the data for each wave (6 waves available) and modified the moderator (age) since people are growing older. So now I have estimates for f.e. the c1-path (variable one lagged effect on variable two) for each age and wave. These are basically regression weights for which I have standard errors. I now want the MEAN effect of age 18 and so on with NEW standard errors. How do I calculate these new standard errors? I took the mean of all weights but the standard error is also dependant on the sample size right? How would I do that? I'm currently using the following code but it seems to be faulty:

```
#calculate new standard errors for mean weights
resultsse_c1 <- data.frame(moderator_mod=numeric(0), se_mean_weight=numeric(0), se=numeric(0))
# Define the age range
age_range <- 39:88

# Iterate over all ages
for(i in age_range){
  
  # Subset the data for age i
  age_data_c1 <- c1[c1$moderator_mod == i,]
  
  # Calculate the mean weight
  mean_weight_c1 <- mean(age_data_c1$est)
  
  # Calculate the new SE
  se_mean_weight_c1 <- sqrt(sum((age_data_c1$se[!is.na(age_data_c1$se)])^2, na.rm = TRUE)/length(age_data_c1$se)) #shouldn't be this way. Why are there even missings in the se?? 
  
  # Append the results to the data frame
  resultsse_c1 <- rbind(resultsse_c1, data.frame(age=i, mean_weight=mean_weight_c1, se_mean_weight=se_mean_weight_c1))
}
#1 duplicate row, no clue why, figure out later
resultsse_c1 <- unique(resultsse_c1)
df_mean_estimate_c1 <- c1 %>% group_by(moderator_mod) %>% summarize(mean_estimatebyage = mean(est))
df_mean_estimate_c1 <- cbind(resultsse_c1, df_mean_estimate_c1)

#calculate new standard errors for mean weights
resultsse_c1 <- data.frame(moderator_mod=numeric(0), se_mean_weight=numeric(0), se=numeric(0))
# Define the age range
age_range <- 39:88

# Iterate over all ages
for(i in age_range){
  
  # Subset the data for age i
  age_data_c1 <- c1[c1$moderator_mod == i,]
  
  # Calculate the mean weight
  mean_weight_c1 <- mean(age_data_c1$est)
  
  # Calculate the new SE
  se_mean_weight_c1 <- sqrt(sum((age_data_c1$se[!is.na(age_data_c1$se)])^2, na.rm = TRUE)/length(age_data_c1$se)) #shouldn't be this way. Why are there even missings in the se?? 
  
  # Append the results to the data frame
  resultsse_c1 <- rbind(resultsse_c1, data.frame(age=i, mean_weight=mean_weight_c1, se_mean_weight=se_mean_weight_c1))
}
#1 duplicate row, no clue why, figure out later
resultsse_c1 <- unique(resultsse_c1)
df_mean_estimate_c1 <- c1 %>% group_by(moderator_mod) %>% summarize(mean_estimatebyage = mean(est))
df_mean_estimate_c1 <- cbind(resultsse_c1, df_mean_estimate_c1)
```